# Proving $f$ is infinitely differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Suppose$$
> f(x)=\begin{cases}
> \exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{x-a}-\dfrac{1}{x-b}\right); & x \in (a,b)\\
> 0; & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Show that $f \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$.

I think I have to just find the general form of the $n$<sup>th</sup> derivative and argue on that, or , go by induction, any idea?

Comment: Your definition is wrong.  Maybe just a copying error.  Should be $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{1}{b-x}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think your function is supposed to be, for $x \in (a,b)$,
$$
f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x-a} - \frac{1}{b-x}}.
$$
The way you had it before with $-1/(x - b)$ can't be right because $-1/(x-b)$ would approach $+\infty$ as $x \to b$ with $x < b$. Define, for $x \in (a,\infty)$,
$$
f_1(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x-a}}
$$
and $f_1(x) = 0$ otherwise, and define, for $x \in (-\infty,b)$,
$$
f_2(x) = e^{- \frac{1}{b-x}},
$$
and $f_2(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then,
$$
f(x) = f_1(x)\cdot f_2(x).
$$
It follows that all we have to do is prove that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in $C^\infty(R)$. Consider $f_1$, as $f_2$ is proven similarly. By an induction argument, one can show that (just take a few derivatives and you'll see the pattern): For all $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$,
$$
f_1^{(n)}(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{p_{n-1}(x)}{(x-a)^{2n}} \, e^{-\frac{1}{x-a}} & \text{if}\ x \in (a,\infty),\\
0 & \text{if}\ x \leq a, \end{cases}
$$
where $p_{n-1}(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $(n-1)$ and moreover that for all $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ that $f_1^{(n)}$ is continuous. This proves that $f_1 \in C^\infty$. Similarly, $f_2 \in C^\infty$. Thus, $f \in C^\infty$. Since it has compact support, $f \in C^\infty_c$.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I see my answer was wrong. Any Idea how I can prove that?

Comment: @Susan I modified the answer

Comment: Actually, you still have to argue separately for $x=a$ and $x=b$... For example, while  $f^{(n)}_1(x) = 0$ for $x<a$, and so $\lim_{x\to a-} f^{(n)}_1(x) = 0$ is clear, you  do need to show $f_1^{(n)}(a) = 0$, and then that the  $ \lim_{x\to a+} f^{(n)}_1(x) = 0$. For instance,  $f_1$ is continuous at $x=a$ because  $f_1(x) = 0$ for $x\le a$ and $$ \lim_{x\to a^+} e^{-1/(x-a)} = \lim_{x\to a^+} {1\over e^{1/(x-a)} } = 0.$$

Comment: @peterag Yes, but your statement is already part of the induction. In the induction you have to prove that the formula for $f_1^{(n)}(x)$ is valid at $x = a$ (see the $x \leq a$ part of the formula for $f_1^{(n)}(x)$ --- in particular, you need to prove $f_1^{(n)}(x) = 0$ at $x = a$).

Comment: @Julie - I agree - with a quibble! It's worth pointing out that the end points 'are special cases.' For instance, to calculate $f_1'(a) $, you need to do the right hand limit separately -  $$ \lim_{h\to 0^+} { e^{-1/h} -0 \over h} = \lim_{h\to 0^+} {1/h \over  e^{1/h}} = \lim_{u\to \infty} {u \over e^u} = 0,$$ the last by de l'hospital rule, or the general 'exponentials beat polynomials' fact which is probably more useful here, for the induction case...